# confusion passing variable to php through multiple scripts

Tags: javascript, php, variables

I am having difficulty passing a variable from a first form to a second form.  There are four scripts involved: debug.php, getVar.php, printme.php and scripta.php.  Running debug.php and typing "blah" for a "password to continue", select scripta.php from the pulldown and hit "Submit", I expect to see $dbpass="blah" for all of the scripts.  I see it for the first page, but after the second pages' "Submit" button is pressed, the value is forgotten once inside of "printme.php".  I suspect this has to do with variable scope.  Any help is appreciated.

debug.php:

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="gateway" action= "" method="POST">
<fieldset>
<label>password to continue:</label>
<input type="text" id="dbpass" name="dbpass">
<label>Select Script:</label>
<select name="scriptSelect" id="scriptSelect">
<option value="">Please make a selection</option>
<option value="scripta.php">scripta</option>
</select>
<input name="updateGateway" type="submit" value="Submit">
<input name="resetForm" id="resetForm" type="reset" value="Reset Form">
</fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('scriptSelect').addEventListener('change', function(e){
        var selected_value = e.target.value;
        document.forms['gateway'].action = selected_value;
        alert(selected_value);
});
</script>
```

scripta.php:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php require 'getVar.php'; ?>
<form name="secondform" action= "printme.php" method="POST">
<fieldset>
<label>Hit submit to continue:</label>
<input name="updateScripta" type="submit" value="Submit">
</fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

getVar.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['dbpass'])) {
        $dbpass = @$_POST["dbpass"];
}
echo "you entered $dbpass";
?>
```

printme.php:

```
<?php
echo "Inside of printme, you entered $dbpass";
?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

2. In scripta.php, add the line: `<input type="hidden" name="dbpass" value="<? echo $dbpass ?>" />` somewhere inside the form tag.
3. In printme.php, add this line at the top of the page `<? $dbpass = $_POST['dbpass'] ?>`

There may be other errors in the scripts you have provided. Check back once you have made the above changes.

Comment: Regarding point 1, the action attribute is actually set by this line: `document.forms['gateway'].action = selected_value;`

Comment: I had glanced over the JS. Yes, you can ignore my first comment then.

Answer (score 0):

Mate... that's not how it works... **Each request is independent**...

In order to pass a value from one script to the other you either use sessions ([$_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)) or you need to repost the variable.

Also, I don't know what you're trying to accomplish but passing passwords around, in plain text...

---

### Repost variables

In scripta.php add this

```
<input name="dbpass" value="<?php $dbpass; ?>" type="hidden"/>
```

to your form. This will send the value contained in `$dbpass` in a hidden value.

Then, in printme.php you need to retrieve the value so just require that `getVar.php script`

```
require 'getVar.php';
echo "Inside of printme, you entered $dbpass";
```

---

### Using Sessions:

change your **getVar.php**

```
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['dbpass'])) {
    $_SESSION['dbpass'] = $_POST["dbpass"]; // you don't need that @
} else {
    $_SESSION['dbpass'] = null;
}
```

then in your subsequent scripts, everytime you want to access dbpass just use

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['dbpass']
```

example:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['dbpass']
echo "Inside of printme, you entered $dbpass";
```

Comment: tried the repost approach with no luck :(   scripta:
sorry having problems formatting in the comments 
`<html>
<body>
<?php require 'getVar.php'; ?>
<form name="secondform" action= "printme.php" method="POST">
<fieldset>
<input name="dbpass" value="<?php $dbpass; ?>" type="hidden"/>
<label>Hit submit to continue:</label>
<input name="updateScripta" type="submit" value="Submit">
</fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: here is printme.php:
`<?php
require 'getVar.php';
echo "Inside of printme, you entered $dbpass";
?>`

Comment: are either of the methods "safe" for passing passwords around?  Thanks

Comment: @sonicnuance no.
Sessions store its value in cookies. Storing credentials in $_SESSION is very unsafe. Passing the password around in hidden form fields is also extremely unsafe.

For authentication purposes you can use oAuth. To secure communication use SSL.

Comment: Is using an https address for all the php files a safe way to handle this?

Comment: NO! HTTPS provides security on the communication layer. It's very important, but you need to take other precautions like not storing the password in plain text, not storing sensible information in the client side cookies, etc...

Comment: oh snap :)   is there a guide or something I can look up for common ways to handle a "enter password to continue" scenario?